How to get rid of sql_mode only_full_group_by
I am using MySQL docker container and I got an error
"which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" so that I tried to remove 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' from sql_mode.
However, after I tried removing it, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" still remains in my sql mode.
I tried "set global sql_mode=" command but "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" still remains.
This is my sql mode list : ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
I used this command.
"set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"

It looks to me like the problem is in the original query that triggered the error.  What was that query?
